# MYSQL JOIN if field is not null

Tags: mysql, database, join

I want to get data from database by reading one whole table, join another one and one more but the last one only if the specified field in first isn't NULL. Here's the query:

```
SELECT a.*, u1.Name, u2.Name FROM `articles` a
JOIN `users` u1 ON (a.id=1 AND u1.`id` = a.`authorid` )
JOIN `users` u2 ON (a.`updaterid` IS NOT NULL AND u2.`id` = a.`updaterid`)
```

Should work okay but it does not. It returns valid result if updaterid isn't NULL but if it is, I keep getting empty result. Any ideas on this one?

PS I also tried some combinations around this e.g. with WHERE or different kinds of JOINs.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (you didn't provide any examlpe data), this query provides the data you want:

```
SELECT a.*, u1.Name, u2.Name FROM `articles` a
JOIN `users` u1 ON (a.id=1 AND u1.`id` = a.`authorid` )
LEFT JOIN `users` u2 ON (a.`updaterid` IS NOT NULL AND u2.`id` = a.`updaterid`)
```

`u2.Name` will be `NULL` if `a.updaterid`IS NULL` (or the updater-user is deleted) or will hold the name otherwise.

Comment: As can be seen example data isn't needed here. Whole case was about concept. That left join there works great, thanks a lot !! :)

Comment: For an exlpenation when to use JOIN and when LEFT JOIN see http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2):

Make both joins outer joins.

```
SELECT a.*, u1.Name, u2.Name 
FROM `articles` a
   Left JOIN `users` u1 
      ON u1.`id` = a.`authorid`
        AND a.id=1
   left JOIN `users` u2 
      ON  u2.`id` = a.`updaterid`
         AND a.`updaterid` IS NOT NULL
```

and once you do that you probably don't need the `is not null` condition...

```
SELECT a.*, u1.Name, u2.Name 
FROM `articles` a
   Left JOIN `users` u1 
      ON u1.`id` = a.`authorid`
        AND a.id=1
   left JOIN `users` u2 
      ON  u2.`id` = a.`updaterid`
```