# How to join to table2 if the table2 id in table1 is not null

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. I want to get all of the data from table1 and all of the data from table2 if the table2 id in table1 is not null.
I want 2 tables in case the user has 2 addresses.

**table1**:
id, name, phone, table2id
table2id can be null or id from table2 if a row exists

**table2**:
id, address, state, country

I have this query but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`table2id` = `table2`.`id` WHERE `table1`.`id` = '2' AND `table1`.`table2id` IS NOT NULL
```

From what I have read, I think I might need a sub select, or IF NOT NULL, but I am not sure how to structure them.
Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582387/mysql-join-if-field-is-not-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your table structure is incorrect. It would be better for you put the foreing key at table 2, so you can have N addresses to each record at table 1.

Like this:

**Table1**: id, name, phone
**Table2**: id, address, state, country, table1id.

With that you can use a `LEFT JOIN` to select all records from Table1 even it doesnt have any address related at Table2.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.TABLE1ID)
```

The records of the `SELECT` result that have Table2 fields with NULL value doesnt have any address.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I want to have multiple addresses for one user.  I wasn't thinking about it correctly with the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  to solve it:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.table2id = table2.id WHERE table1.id = '2';
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but Filipes answer was what I really needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` for that, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.phone, t2.address, t2.state, t2.country
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.table2id = t2.id
WHERE t1.id = 2;
```

It will return null values for `t2.*` columns if there is no matching row.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html) MySQL documentation for `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks for answering but Filipes answer was what I really needed to do.